Using chrome extension javascript code across multiple files and appeasing ESLint
I have developed a chrome extension where, in order to try and keep code managable, have broken the content script code into 5 separate js files which are injected from the serviceWorker like this if the URL matches a specific site;
                    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                        target: { tabId },
                        files: [
                            'content/globals.js',
                            'content/hotkey_configs.js',
                            'content/element_control.js',
                            'content/socket-manager.js',
                            'content/textmanager.js',
                            'content/content.js',
                        ],
                    });

All is good, things are working but most of these files access functions and variables through the various files.
I recently started using ESlint and it is very angry at me since I have functions spread out across the different files and it thinks it can't find them.
For example;
file1.js
function lockTarget() {
   ...Some function
}

file2.js
lockTarget();  //ESlint  reports that lockTarget is not defined

I have these little things all over when access data or functions in different files. I have added some global references to eslintrc like "chrome" and a few others I have defined and that addressed those.
I guess my question is: Should I should listen to ESlint and restructure my code to appease it or just add exceptions to my eslintrc file since what I'm doing is ok?

You can 1) manually declare the globals using eslint comments or config, 2) use a bundler with normal modules to produce a single content script file.
